# Is multiple imputation recommended to handle attrition?

Tags: multiple-imputation

I have PRE-POST data from a psychotherapy group intervention, including measures on anxiety, depression, QoL, coping, self-esteem, as well as demographic variables. I´m performing a t-test to examine changes from PRE-POST and a path analysis to examine the effect of coping on anxiety, depression, and QoL at T2 while controlling for the T1 measures.

The data is showing an attrition rate of about 20% (from N=55 at T1 to N=45at T2).

My questions:

1-Is it recommended to use multiple imputation to handle attrition in this case?

2-Could anyone please point me out to a good article/resource related to this situation?

3-Does multiple imputation work at the item level? I am missing entire responses to instruments but also responses to specific items within instruments.

Comment: Hi @EdM, I´m not sure how to do that. I only conducted a t-test analysis to see whether participants who dropped out differed in any variable from those who completed T2 measures. There were no differences.

Comment: That's a good start. You could also try a combined multiple logistic regression of your indicator variable for dropping out (outcome variable) against the pre-intervention variable values as predictors. That might show some effects that your variable-by-variable t-tests could miss.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. And depending on whether there are or aren´t any effects on drop out it would appropriate (or not) to do multiple imputation for the missing values post-intervention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stef van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/) is a good introduction to this subject. You might also want to look at: Schafer, J. L., and J. W. Graham. 2002. “[Missing Data: Our View of the State of the Art](http://content.apa.org/journals/met/7/2/147).” Psychological Methods 7 (2): 147–77.
Those authors discuss your issue of losses of individual items versus loss of entire instruments.

The main assumption you require is that the missing data are "missing at random," in the technical sense explained in those references. Essentially, it's OK if the probability of missingness depends on the values of observed data, but it's not "missing at random" if the probability of missingness depends on unavailable information.

So applying that principle to your case, you are probably safe in imputing the individual items. You do, however, have to think about whether, say, those who dropped out of your study tended to be those for whom your interventions did not work and became more anxious or depressed.

Also, consider your audience. Some clinicians are highly reluctant to believe results of multiple imputation, clinging to the incorrect idea that it's just "making up data." If your data are "missing completely at random," in the sense that the probability of missingness doesn't depend on either the missing data or the observed data, then restricting to those who completed both instruments just costs you a bit of power, which might be worth it in practice for convincing that type of audience of your result.

My initial comment, in retrospect, was misleading and I will delete it. You should certainly investigate whether dropping out is related to pre-intervention variable values, but not for the reason I suggested.